# ASP.NET Web Forms - Global Procedures

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

is there a way to create a page similar to a module in windows form projects where I can have multiple procedures/functions and to be able to call and access them from multiple pages? Thank you.
- Gabe

Answer (score 0):

Modules are a VB.Net feature, available in all VB.Net project types.

In C#, you can [create a `static class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).

Comment: Would I create my 'function' under a class page? i.e. and then have multiple pages call that class and method?